how to transition lower tile to higher laminate
I am installing laminate flooring and it butts up against some tile that I want to keep.  The laminate flooring (Pergo) and underlayment are 1/2" TALLER than the tile.  The transition pieces do not smooth or "transition" without a tiny gap.  How can I seal this gap?

Also How can I transition between these floors?

Threshold bar for fixed height difference:

The above needs to be just the right height, otherwise it'll look ugly. So it's hard to find. The next one can allow more "play" in the height, but not too much, otherwise it'll end up crooked and grab a shoe:

Adjustable height:

The last one is the easiest to install. The wider the better, as the slope will be smoother and it is easier to hide an imperfect laminate cut on the edge.
Models without screws do look nicer, but the fastening systems are usually quite flimsy and difficult to work with. Nothing beats the good old screw.
When joining tile and laminate, you have to account for the wood laminate's expansion and contraction with humidity. So it must be able to slide slightly under the bar. Mounting it with screws allows this, but they should not be tightened too hard. To help the laminate slide under it when it expands, you can apply adhesive felt tape, sticking it on the underside of the bar.
If you glue it, for this reason you should only glue one side. I don't like glue much: if you need to remove the bar for some reason (for example the glue becoming unglued on one end) the rest of the glue that still holds can rip the surface off the laminate or leave nasty residue...
